# Mixed language code documentation - need help to debug doxygen

Tags: c++, c, fortran, doxygen

I would be glad to make the code documentation of our big project, http://www.diracprogram.org, which is a mixture of `F90`, `F77`, Fortran include files, `C` and `C++` source code files. Plus a lot of preprocessor statements (mainly in Fortran files).

I am using `Doxygen 1.8.6`, and playing with the Doxygen.in configuration file and the doxygen debug statements.

Fortran is the main language.

As you can see, there is a lot of errors. Any clue how to track, understand them and then adapt the Fortran source files accordingly?

```
********************************************************************
Error in file /home/ilias/Dokumenty/Work/QCH/software/dirac_git/working_trunk/utils/mx2fit.F90 line: 621, state: 21
********************************************************************
********************************************************************
Error in file /home/ilias/Dokumenty/Work/QCH/software/dirac_git/working_trunk/utils/polfit.F90 line: 168, state: 21
********************************************************************
********************************************************************
Error in file /home/ilias/Dokumenty/Work/QCH/software/dirac_git/working_trunk/utils/twofit.F90 line: 310, state: 21
********************************************************************
********************************************************************
Error in file /home/ilias/Dokumenty/Work/QCH/software/dirac_git/working_trunk/src/amfi/amfi3.F line: 2824, state: 4
********************************************************************
********************************************************************
Error in file /home/ilias/Dokumenty/Work/QCH/software/dirac_git/working_trunk/src/cc_external/hsfscc/chp_11a.F90 line: 1993, state: 21
********************************************************************
parse error in end <scopename>********************************************************************
Error in file /home/ilias/Dokumenty/Work/QCH/software/dirac_git/working_trunk/src/dirac/dirbss.F line: 7884, state: 6
********************************************************************
/home/ilias/Dokumenty/Work/QCH/software/dirac_git/working_trunk/src/include/dcbgascip.h:37: warning: Found ';' while parsing initializer list! (doxygen could be confused by a mac
ro call without semicolon)
/home/ilias/Dokumenty/Work/QCH/software/dirac_git/working_trunk/src/include/dcbham.h:50: warning: Found ';' while parsing initializer list! (doxygen could be confused by a macro 
call without semicolon)
parse error in end <scopename>********************************************************************
Error in file /home/ilias/Dokumenty/Work/QCH/software/dirac_git/working_trunk/src/krmc/krmcgascip.F line: 4684, state: 6
********************************************************************
********************************************************************
Error in file /home/ilias/Dokumenty/Work/QCH/software/dirac_git/working_trunk/src/reladc/adccore.F line: 7170, state: 19
********************************************************************
********************************************************************
Error in file /home/ilias/Dokumenty/Work/QCH/software/dirac_git/working_trunk/src/reladc/adcdble.F line: 2871, state: 10
********************************************************************
********************************************************************
Error in file /home/ilias/Dokumenty/Work/QCH/software/dirac_git/working_trunk/src/reladc/adcdiag.F line: 4813, state: 10
********************************************************************
********************************************************************
Error in file /home/ilias/Dokumenty/Work/QCH/software/dirac_git/working_trunk/src/reladc/adcexci.F line: 1995, state: 10
********************************************************************
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/doxygen] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
make[3]: Target `CMakeFiles/doxygen.dir/build' not remade because of errors.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/doxygen.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/doxygen.dir/rule] Error 2
make[1]: Target `doxygen' not remade because of errors.
make: *** [doxygen] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

First I assume that the code compiles correctly.

It is also advised to upgrade to the newest version of doxygen (currently 1.8.8) as a number of problems might be solved.

Best way to track down is (unfortunately in case of the state errors the reported line number is, most of the time, of no use):
- study the doxygen code
- for each file run doxygen on it separately and try to solve the problem by e.g. reducing the file till the error disappears and conclude from this what was wrong.
- build doxygen yourself and run with flex in debug mode / add print statements

For each of the *.F90 lines you should see in the output line similar to:

> ```
> Preprocessing .../a.F90... 
> Parsing file .../a.F90...
> ```

for each *.f90 file:

> ```
> Reading .../a.f90...
> Parsing file .../a.f90...
> ```

for each *.F file:

> ```
> Preprocessing .../a.F...
> Prepassing fixed form of .../a.F
> Parsing file ...a.F...
> ```

for each *.f file:

> ```
> Reading .../a.f...
> Prepassing fixed form of .../a.f
> Parsing file .../a.f...
> ```

When this is not the case the file is not properly recognized as free formatted Fortran / fixed formatted code and doxygen might get confused.
This can be accomplished by defining in the Doxyfile:

> ```
> EXTENSION_MAPPING      = f=FortranFixed f90=FortranFree
> ```

(this is possible since version 1.8.7 of doxygen)
when this is not possible set in the first column of the first line of a *.f / *.F file a 'C'. 'c' or '*'.

On the site of www.diracprogram.org I could not find the source code, is it possible to share (part?).

Now something about the different states, they come from fortranscanner.l (for a solution I have to make a guess):

- state: 4

  SubprogBody: probably due to not properly closed / recognized subroutine body in fixed formatted code (as it is a .F file, so add 'C' ...)
- state: 6

  Start: probably due to not properly closed / recognized start condition in fixed formatted code (as it is a .F file, so add 'C' ...)
- state: 10

  ModuleBody: probably due to not properly closed / recognized module body in fixed formatted code (as it is a .F file, so add 'C' ...)
- state: 19

  InterfaceBody: probably due to not properly closed / recognized interface in fixed formatted code (as it is a .F file, so add 'C' ...)
- state: 21

  String: string not properly closed string or string quotes somewhere in comment

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I installed doxygen 1.8.8 and after deactivating some of *.F files I got the documentation (though with many errors from other F77-source files). Concerning the diracprogram.org - could we please speak privately ? (Miroslav.Ilias at umb dot sk)

Comment: @albert, Where can I find more of those error codes??? I cannot for the life of me find a compilation of where those are, and I can't find fortranscanner.l on my system (I'm not admin)

Comment: @Ajean Which version of doxygen do you use? In the newer versions a mnemonic is given for the these error codes in Fortran. When you find one just try to make a small source reproducing the problem (in a new question), so one can give you some advise when necessary. The doxygen source code is available on Github (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen) and the fortranscanner.l can be found here in the sub-directory src.

Comment: @albert Ah, thank you so much! I found the fortranscanner.l on GitHub and found the listing, that helps although less than I thought it would.  The version is 1.8.5, although the code I am working with is so old that I don't know if I should blame Doxygen  or the code itself, since it is seg faulting with 1.8.5 and it didn't with the old version it was working with before (1.6.1).  My guess is the code, frankly.

Comment: @Ajean Doxygen version 1.8.5 is also a very old version of doxygen (August 23, 2013) so I would definitely advise to update to the current doxygen version (1.9.1). Maybe fortunately for you after version 1.8.4 the development of doxygen is done with git(hub). It might be that the problems comes from the code to document, but still would be interesting to know whether or not the problem still occurs in 1.9.1 (and when this is the case to have a minimal working example showing the problem).

Comment: @albert oh I wish. I'm not allowed to install anything (even a local install from source, so unfortunately access to the most recent code on github doesn't help) so I'll have to poke the admins and keep my fingers crossed. If I can get the version upgraded and I'm still facing the issue I might post a question here.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ajean Yes you definitely should push the admin guys and otherwise push the management as well, the OS, compilers, etc.  you are using probably aren't  from 2013 either, otherwise there would probably be big security risks.